# PHP: Session variable does not increase in first iteration

Tags: php, html, session, session-variables

I've written a short PHP programm which shows two pictures. With 2 radio buttons, you have to choose one and then you have to click the submit button. Then, the page saves the vote for the picture you have chosen and then shows the next two pictures. 
I use a session variable to store, which images have to be showed. 
Unfortunately, the variable is not increased after the first click on the "next" button. After, it works perfectly well.

What is wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<?php   
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['image_nr'])) { /* If there is already a value set */
        $x = $_SESSION['image_nr'];

        echo $x;
    }   
    else { 

        $_SESSION['image_nr'] = 1; /* Set to 1 */
        $x = $_SESSION['image_nr'];
    }

    include('sql/db_connect.php');
    include('sql/queries.php');


    if($x == 9){
        increaseParticipants();
        $_POST['submit']='';
        $_SESSION['image_nr'] = 1;
        session_unset($_SESSION['image_nr']);
        header( "Location: thankyou.php" );
    }       
?>
<html>
    <header>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="functions.js"></script>       
    </header>
    <body>
        <form action= "" method = "post">
            <div class='content' id='image1'><?php if($x == 1){echo"<img src='images/image_1.jpg' width='380'><br>Image 1";}?></div>
            <div class='content2' id='image2'><?php if($x == 1){echo"<img src='images/image_2.jpg' width='380'><br>Image 2";}?></div>

            <div id='bottom'>


                <input type='radio' name='radio' id='radio1' value='<?php echo $x; ?>' onchange="enableButton()"> Image <?php echo $x; ?> <br>
                <input type='radio' name='radio' id='radio2' value='<?php echo ($x+1);?>' onchange="enableButton()"> Image <?php echo $x+1; ?><br>
                <input type="submit" id="button" name= "submit" value="Next" onclick="saveClick()" disabled />

            </div>      

        <?php
            if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']!='') {
                if(isset($_POST['radio'])) {
                    $image = $_POST['radio'];
                    increaseClicks($image);
                    $x = $x+2;          
                }

                $_SESSION['image_nr'] = $x;
                $next = getNext($image);
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
                    , 'changeImage('.$next.');'
                    , '</script>'

                ;
                $_POST['submit']='';
            }
        ?>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Here are the JS functions:

```
function enableButton(){
        document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;
}


function changeImage(next){


    var firstpart = "<img src='images/image_";
    var secondpart = ".jpg' width='380'><br>Bild"+next;
    var inHtml = firstpart.concat(next, secondpart);
    document.getElementById("bild1").innerHTML = inHtml;
    var secondpart = ".jpg' width='380'><br>Bild"+(next+1);
    var inHtml = firstpart.concat((next+1), secondpart);
    document.getElementById("bild2").innerHTML = inHtml;

}
```

And the queries (I know that these are deprecated)

```
<?php

function getClicks ($image){

    $q1 = "SELECT clicks from tbl_clicks WHERE ID_bild=".$image;
    $rq1 = mysql_query($q1);
    $return = mysql_fetch_array($rq1);
    $number_of_clicks = $return['clicks'];
    return $number_of_clicks;
}


function getClicksAll (){
    $q1 = "SELECT ID_bild, name, clicks from tbl_clicks";
    $rq1 = mysql_query($q1);
    return $rq1;
}

function increaseClicks ($image){

    $clicks = getClicks($image);
    $clicks = (int)$clicks;
    $clicks = $clicks + 1;
    echo "this are the clicks: ".$clicks;
    $q2 = "UPDATE tbl_clicks SET clicks = ".$clicks." WHERE ID_bild = ".$image;
    mysql_query ($q2);
}

function getNext ($image){

    $q3 = "SELECT next from tbl_clicks WHERE ID_bild=".$image;
    $rq3 = mysql_query($q3);
    $return = mysql_fetch_array($rq3);
    $next = $return['next'];    
    return $next;

}

function getParticipants(){

    $q4 = "SELECT participants from tbl_participants";
    $rq4 = mysql_query($q4);
    $return = mysql_fetch_array($rq4);
    $participants = $return['participants'];
    return $participants;
}

function increaseParticipants(){
    $participants = getParticipants();
    $q5 = "UPDATE tbl_participants SET participants = ".($participants+1);
    mysql_query ($q5);
}

?>
```

Comment: print_r() the session variable and let us know

Comment: What does increaseClicks do?

Comment: @user3386779 It prints a 1 when I print in the first php part and a 3 when I print in the second php part. But it should be a 3 and 5...

Comment: @Orlangure: it gets the current clicks of that pictures out of the database and then increases by 1 and stores the new value in the database. It's a simple update query.

Comment: Post the code of this function please

Comment: thats your value is assigned to session variable rite? or what you need exactly

Comment: @Orlangure: `function increaseClicks ($image){
 
 
 $clicks = getClicks($image);
 $clicks = (int)$clicks;
 $clicks = $clicks + 1;

 $sql = "UPDATE tbl_clicks SET clicks = ".$clicks." WHERE ID_bild = ".$image;
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,, $sql);
}`

Comment: @user3386779: Yes, first, when the session variable not yet exists, I set 1 and then it should increase by two.